# How to get the country, city, state name from google place detail api

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, laravel, codeigniter

I want to get the Place detail using the place id from google map webservice api

I have called the api url using: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY

I am getting response from google like this :

```
{
"html_attributions" : [],
"result" : {
    "address_components" : [
        {
            "long_name" : "5",
            "short_name" : "5",
            "types" : [ "floor" ]
        },
        {
            "long_name" : "48",
            "short_name" : "48",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
            "long_name" : "Pirrama Road",
            "short_name" : "Pirrama Rd",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
            "long_name" : "Pyrmont",
            "short_name" : "Pyrmont",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
            "long_name" : "Council of the City of Sydney",
            "short_name" : "Sydney",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
            "long_name" : "New South Wales",
            "short_name" : "NSW",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
            "long_name" : "Australia",
            "short_name" : "AU",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
            "long_name" : "2009",
            "short_name" : "2009",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
    ],
    "adr_address" : "5, \u003cspan class=\"street-address\"\u003e48 Pirrama Rd\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003ePyrmont\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003eNSW\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003e2009\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eAustralia\u003c/span\u003e",
    "formatted_address" : "5, 48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont NSW 2009, Australia",
    "formatted_phone_number" : "(02) 9374 4000",
    "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
            "lat" : -33.866651,
            "lng" : 151.195827
        },
        "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : -33.8653881697085,
               "lng" : 151.1969739802915
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : -33.86808613029149,
               "lng" : 151.1942760197085
            }
        }
    },
    "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
    "id" : "4f89212bf76dde31f092cfc14d7506555d85b5c7",
    "international_phone_number" : "+61 2 9374 4000",
    "name" : "Google",
    "place_id" : "ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4",
    "rating" : 4.5,
    "reference" : "CmRSAAAAjiEr2_A4yI-DyqGcfsceTv-IBJXHB5-W3ckmGk9QAYk4USgeV8ihBcGBEK5Z1w4ajRZNVAfSbROiKbbuniq0c9rIq_xqkrf_3HpZzX-pFJuJY3cBtG68LSAHzWXB8UzwEhAx04rgN0_WieYLfVp4K0duGhTU58LFaqwcaex73Kcyy0ghYOQTkg",
    "reviews" : [
        {
            "author_name" : "Robert Ardill",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106422854611155436041/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-T47KxWuAoJU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAZo/BDmyI12BZAs/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba1/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "a month ago",
            "text" : "Awesome offices. Great facilities, location and views. Staff are great hosts",
            "time" : 1491144016
        }
    ],
    "scope" : "GOOGLE",
    "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
    "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=10281119596374313554",
    "utc_offset" : 600,
    "vicinity" : "5, 48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont",
    "website" : "https://www.google.com.au/about/careers/locations/sydney/"
},
"status" : "OK"
```

}

So please help me to get the Country and State name from the result

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this and you will get the state and country

```
$json = json_decode($result);

foreach ($json->results as $result) {
    foreach($result->address_components as $addressPart) {
       if ((in_array('locality', $addressPart->types)) && (in_array('political', $addressPart->types)))
       $city = $addressPart->long_name;
        else if ((in_array('administrative_area_level_1', $addressPart->types)) && (in_array('political', $addressPart->types)))
       $state = $addressPart->long_name;
       else if ((in_array('country', $addressPart->types)) && (in_array('political', $addressPart->types)))
       $country = $addressPart->long_name;
    }
}
```